# Prolog - How to make a list of lists with a certain length from a flat list

Tags: list, prolog, chunking

For example:

```
createlistoflists([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], NewLists)
NewLists = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9].
```

So basically my first argument is a list, my second argument a new list consisting of lists with the proper length (the proper length being 3). My first idea was to use append of some sort. But I have literally no idea how to do this, any thoughts?

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see in your example how you are specifying the "proper length". Are you assuming it's always (hard coded to) 3? Also, what if you do `createlistoflists([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], NewLists)`? What result do you expect?

Comment: Yes the proper length is hardcoded to 3, the result I wrote under. NewLists should output a list, with 3 lists in it with a length of 3.

Comment: Right, but what result do you expect from `createlistoflists([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], NewLists)`? You want it to just fail?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using the nice facilities Prolog provides you, there's a simple approach;

```
list_length(Size, List) :- length(List, Size).

split_list(List, SubSize, SubLists) :-
    maplist(list_length(SubSize), SubLists),
    append(SubLists, List).
```

And you can query it as:

```
?-  split_list([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 3, L).
L = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

It will fail if `List` is instantiated in such a way that it's length is not a multiple of `SubSize`.

---

As pointed out by Will Ness in the comments, the above simple solution has a flaw: the `maplist(list_length(SubSize), SubList)` will continue to query and find longer and longer sets of sublists, unconstrained. Thus, on retry, the query above will not terminate.

The temptation would be to use a cut like so:

```
split_list(List, SubSize, SubLists) :-
    maplist(list_length(SubSize), SubLists), !,
    append(SubLists, List).
```

The cut here assumes you just want to get a single answer as if you were writing an imperative function.

A better approach is to try to constrain, in a logical way, the `SubList` argument to `maplist`. A simple approach would be to ensure that the length of `SubList` doesn't exceed the length of `List` since, logically, it should never be greater. Adding in this constraint:

```
list_length(Size, List) :- length(List, Size).

not_longer_than([], []).
not_longer_than([], [_|_]).
not_longer_than([_|X], [_|Y]) :-
    not_longer_than(X, Y).

split_list(List, SubSize, SubLists) :-
    not_longer_than(SubLists, List),
    maplist(list_length(SubSize), SubLists),
    append(SubLists, List).
```

Then the query terminates without losing generality of the solution:

```
?- split_list([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 3, L).
L = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] ;
false.

?-
```

One could be more precise in the implementation of `not_longer_than/2` and have it use the `SubSize` as a multiple. That would be more efficient but not required to get termination.

```
not_longer_than_multiple(L1, Mult, L2) :-
    not_longer_than_multiple(L1, Mult, Mult, L2).

not_longer_than_multiple([], _, _, []).
not_longer_than_multiple([], _, _, [_|_]).
not_longer_than_multiple([_|Xs], Mult, 1, [_|Ys]) :-
    not_longer_than_multiple(Xs, Mult, Mult, Ys).
not_longer_than_multiple(Xs, Mult, C, [_|Ys]) :-
    C #> 1,
    C1 #= C - 1,
    not_longer_than_multiple(Xs, Mult, C1, Ys).
```

Or something along those lines...

---

But then, if we're going to go through all that non-sense to cover the sins of this use of `maplist`, then perhaps hitting the problem head-on makes the cleanest solution:

```
split_list(List, SubSize, SubLists) :-
    split_list(List, SubSize, SubSize, SubLists).

split_list([], _, _, []).
split_list([X|Xs], SubList, 1, [[X]|S]) :-
    split_list(Xs, SubList, SubList, S).
split_list([X|Xs], SubSize, C, [[X|T]|S]) :-
    C #> 1,
    C1 #= C - 1,
    split_list(Xs, SubSize, C1, [T|S]).
```

Comment: diverges on retry.

Comment: @WillNess thanks for catching that. I'd have sworn I had tested for that, but when I just tried it, indeed, it fails to terminate on retry.

Comment: glad to help. I'm extremely curious how / whether this can be capped *purely*.

Comment: good old-school handmade `not_longer_than`! maybe if you'd forgo the `maplist` altogether, the lists with possibly shorter last group could be handled as well.

Comment: @WillNess yeah, maybe I was hanging on to mapllist irrationally... Originally it seemed like a snappy way, along with `append/2` toward a simple solution. But it did start to get more complex. So, I posted a direct approach which doesn't seem so bad after all.\

Comment: sorry for being such a bother today, :) but I tried `split_list([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 3, L).` and it failed. (and it's not deterministic, but that's much less of a concern). what if we pre-created one list of the given SubSize length at the start, and reused it to count on it by unconsing, without any arithmetic; could that help? it could even allow for a non-ground SubSize... (not sure about that). --- the original was indeed *snappy* - and very cheerful. *too* cheerful (i.e. couldn't stop). :)

Comment: @WillNess `split_list([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 3, L).` fails by design. I think I mentioned it somewhere in my rambling answer. The OP didn't make it clear, but I assumed that the initial list must be a proper integer multiple in length of the second argument. Just keeping it simple, unless the OP wants to state their requirements in more detail.